# Very random empty jsp form data on submit after validation

Tags: java, forms, jsp, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

We have a jsp (2.2)/jstl(2.1) form that submits to a java servlet (3.0) on tomcat 7 server.  Randomly, intermittently we will get a submission to the servlet with all the http request parameter values as null.  Our form has some fields that are pre-populated so we expect at least those to be retrievable but they are null at the serlvet as well.  Almost all of the form submissions we receive contain form data and are successfully processed.  It's the once in every so many submissions that has the completely empty http request parameter set that I cannot figure out nor reproduce. There are no file uploads involved, the data is submitted via post.  We validate client side and server side.  I have searched high and low for reasons why the form data can be empty but have not had any success.  Any thoughts?

1) no file uploads
2) all fields have 'name='
3) method is post
4) data is validated prior to submission
5) implement a filter for db entity management

partial jsp form:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");//Forces caches to obtain a     new copy of the page from the origin server
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");//Directs caches not to store the page under any circumstance
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);//Causes the proxy cache to see the page as "stale"
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");//HTTP 1.0 backward enter code here
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--head/body stuff -->
<form id="app_form" name="app_form" action="process" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">

<!-- general form fields using html/jstl -->

<button type="submit" id="submit_application" name="submit_application" class="submit application submitbtn" title="I'm finished and want to submit my completed application.">SUBMIT APPLICATION</button>

</form>
```

partial filter:

```
public class EntityManagerFilter implements Filter {

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    log.debug("Initializing filter...");
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
}
```

partial java servlet:

```
public class ProcessApplicationFormServlet extends BaseServlet {

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ProcessApplicationFormServlet.class);
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Application_Domestic appdata = null;
Domestic_user currentUser = null;
String sessID = null;
String program = null;
String type = null;

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        //values from form
        appdata.setTitle(maxLength(req.getParameter("title"),25));
        appdata.setFirst(maxLength(req.getParameter("first"),30));
        appdata.setMiddle(maxLength(req.getParameter("middle"),30));
        appdata.setLast(maxLength(req.getParameter("last"),57));
        appdata.setSuffix(maxLength(req.getParameter("suffix"),25));                        
        appdata.setEmail_Address(maxLength(req.getParameter("trueemail"),50)); 
        etc...
        process data 
    }
}
@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
}
```

These are just the portions that deal with submission/http request.  If there are other important coding considerations that I need to show, please let me know.  Do keep in mind that only 1 - 2 percent of the form submissions come in with empty httpServletRequest data.  This code has been tested and working.  I just cannot seem to be able to reproduce the scenario when a user submits the form (it can not be submitted until all data as been validated) and it reaches the servlet with an empty data set where every parameter is null.

Comment: UPDATE:  I updated the servlet to log the request parameters (via enumeration) before processing.  I notice that for those applicants who are unable to successfully submit the form, the http request parameters are missing more than half of the form data. The missing fields include the typical name, addr, city, state, etc.

Comment: ANOTHER UPDATE:  A look at the stack trace shows that when the form is submitted, it is going to doGet rather than doPost.  The form's method is decidedly set to post and 99.5% of the applications are doing just that.  What I am looking to find out is what type of scenario would have the remaining .5% submit as a get rather than post?